# Vagrant Hyper-V provider with Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, vagrant, hyper-v

I'm trying to get the vagrant hyper-v provider to work with a debian 7.4 image, but not having much luck.

1. I created a vagrant box by following the steps in http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/hyperv/boxes.html .
2. I removed all existing hyper-v vms and network switches from hyper-v.
3. I added an "External switch" to hyper-v.
4. Then:

   ```
   [ADMIN] 17:55:06 C:\> cd .\vagrant-test
   [ADMIN] 17:55:08 C:\vagrant-test> ls
   [ADMIN] 17:55:08 C:\vagrant-test> vagrant init debian-wheezy
   A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
   ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
   the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
   `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
   [ADMIN] 17:55:19 C:\vagrant-test> vagrant up --provider=hyperv
   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'hyperv' provider...
   ==> default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
   ==> default: Importing a Hyper-V instance
       default: Cloning virtual hard drive...
       default: Creating and registering the VM...
       default: Successfully imported a VM with name: DebianWheezy74Base
   ==> default: Starting the machine...
   ==> default: Waiting for the machine to report its IP address...
       default: Timeout: 120 seconds
   Hyper-V failed to determine your machine's IP address within the
   configured timeout. Please verify the machine properly booted and
   the network works. To do this, open the Hyper-V manager, find your
   virtual machine, and connect to it.

   The most common cause for this error is that the running virtual
   machine doesn't have the latest Hyper-V integration drivers. Please
   research for your operating system how to install these in order
   for the VM to properly communicate its IP address to Hyper-V.
   [ADMIN] 17:57:55 C:\vagrant-test>
   ```

I've tried the same thing with an internal switch.

That's fair enough, because the way the hyper-v provider tries to find the IP address is via a powershell command like this:

```
[ADMIN] 18:01:18 C:\code\autosetup> Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName DebianWheezy74Base
Name            IsManagementOs VMName             SwitchName      MacAddress   Status                      IPAddresses
----            -------------- ------             ----------      ----------   ------                      -----------
Network Adapter False          DebianWheezy74Base External Switch 00155D890119 {Degraded, ProtocolVersion} {}


[ADMIN] 18:01:25 C:\code\autosetup> (Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName DebianWheezy74Base).IPAddresses
[ADMIN] 18:01:36 C:\code\autosetup>
```

So it can't determine what IP address was actually assigned to the VM. Yes, the VM does actually get an IP very quickly via DHCP.

There are a number of things that point to needing to upgrade the hyper-v integration services on the VM, but hyper-v doesn't "officially" support debian, just RHEL. The downloads Microsoft supplies simply include rpms. Debian *should* already have the proper hyper-v goodness. I see that the hyper-v modules are loaded:

```
root@debian74base:/home/vagrant# lsmod | grep hv_
hv_utils               12986  0
hv_netvsc              18304  0
hv_storvsc             17423  2
hv_vmbus               32029  4 hid_hyperv,hv_storvsc,hv_netvsc,hv_utils
scsi_mod              162269  5 libata,sr_mod,sg,hv_storvsc,sd_mod
```

Has anyone gotten vagrant + hyper-v + debian to work? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the debian/hyper-v/vagrant combo working by building/installing the hv_kvp_daemon (from https://github.com/v10networks/hv_kvp_daemon)

Build the package:

```
apt-get install devscripts git
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/v10networks/hv_kvp_daemon
cd hv_kvp_daemon
debuild -i -us -uc -b
dpkg -i ../hv-userspace-daemons_0.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Set it to run on boot:

```
update-rc.d hv-kvp-daemon defaults.
```

Vagrant (and the Hyper-V manager) was able to detect the IP after that.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer. I haven't tried it, and I have long since abandoned trying to get debian+hyper-v+vagrant to work together. (Instead of using vagrant I spin up and configure the VMs myself, which is not that much work.)

Comment: I imagine that my issue is related to what curriegrad2004 describes [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d2d01d4a-e682-4ea4-8ef6-17daf8a10d35/cannot-see-ipadress-of-linux-vm-in-hyperv-manager-and-vmm?forum=linuxintegrationservices). What version of Windows are you running? I'm on Windows 8.1, which I suspect hits this exact bug, since the kernel in Debian is relatively old.

Comment: Confirmed - upgrading my kernel to 3.14 and using this does work.